# Python rest api Put method throws 500

Tags: python, selenium, rest

I have following python code

https://github.com/salikhanan/my_login_testing/blob/master/login_app/api.py

Here when a put request is made to update user data It throws

```
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
```

while it works fine when a get request is made to retrieve data for a single user.
Can someone see what is wrong with PUT ? I would really appreciate it. I saw this project online to learn automation but I got myself stuck with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 is probably due to an exception being raised and not caught in your application code. You should run your app in development mode:

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

.. then start the server with `flask run`. Now when you get the error, you will see in the browser a traceback pointing out the exact statement which is raising an exception.

Comment: Thankyou so much you are a star, more people like you needed BLESS

Comment: @Maria no problem! maybe accept my answer with the checkmark if it solved your issue..? :)

Comment: Done, I got another error if you can help ? AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: That error is not coming from the code on GH...

Comment: Yeh I have fixed that error, attributes in Header should be double quoted and fixed